# How to drop a remote graph using Java in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I am trying to setup a remote OrientDB Server and I am trying to enter vertices into it from local Java code.

When I try the following code:

```
private static final void dropDb() {
    OrientGraphNoTx graph = new OrientGraphNoTx(ORIENT_URL);
    graph.drop();
}
```

I get an Exception saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot delete database
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot delete a database in a remote server. Please use the console or the OServerAdmin class.
```

How do I go about deleting a remote graph, using Java, in OrientDB?

Answer (score 5):

He jackofblades,

the Graph answers your question:

*Please use the console or the OServerAdmin class*

```
// CREATE A SERVER ADMIN CLIENT AGAINST A REMOTE SERVER
OServerAdmin serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts").connect("admin", "admin");
serverAdmin.dropDatabase("GratefulDeadConcerts");
```

This is taken from the [OrientDB Wiki](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Server-Management-Java) Page

Patrick