# Create schema for graph database with Java in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm trying to create schema for graph database in OrientDB with Java but I have two problems I can't solve. I'm using this example http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Schema.html

1. When I use this code

```java
OServerAdmin serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost").connect("root", "1234");
serverAdmin.createDatabase("mydb", "graph", "plocal");
serverAdmin.close();
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OResourcePool.getAllResources()Ljava/util/Collection;
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.r

It creates the database but nothing more, because I get that exception.

2. I can create the database from the command line instead and then create the schema with Java like:

```java
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/mydb", "root", "1234");         
OrientVertexType userVType = graph.createVertexType("User");
userVType.createProperty("email", OType.STRING)
// ...
```

It works fine but it will try to create the schema every time I run the program and I got the error messages like the user class already exist etc. So I wonder how could I check if the database and the schema already exist or which is the right way to create schema with Java in OrientDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [**here**](http://www.kwoxer.de/2014/11/12/daten-import-via-java-orientdb-real-beispiel-tutorial/) there I show a complete example about creating a graph database.

Some of the main points about that import:

- use always the factory *factoryGraph = new OrientGraphFactory(dbPath, "admin", "admin").setupPool(1, 10);*
- create database structure with the non-graph environment (somehow this works much better I found out after some time)  *db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(dbPath);*
- create helper methods (e.g. *void createProperty(String className, String propertyName, OType oType) {...}*)

I'm working with this way of import in my latest project and having no issues. I also created a technique to save the old functions and after the import I restore them.

If you need more infos let me know and I'll add them here.

Comment: Thanks. Your example was very helpful. I changed my code a lil bit but I still have problems. If I check if the DB exist with your code then I get: Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot check the existance of a database in a remote server. Please use the console or the OServerAdmin class.  If I don't check if the DB exist only try to create it then I get:  Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot create database 'testdb'  Any idea why?

Comment: Yeah for sure the database instance needs to be locally. Maybe that's your main issue?

Comment: Maybe. Isn't it possible to create remote db in Java?

Comment: No it should be possible as well. I just remember some issues. Did you already try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485074/how-to-drop-a-remote-graph-using-java-in-orientdb Your example is a little bit different. You use OServerAdmin but you don't say which database after localhost. Could you check that please?

Comment: Yeah, it's like my example. I tried in many different ways but I always get this error: [error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OResourcePool.getAllResources()Ljava/util/Collection;
 .. and my program stops because of this error. The strange things is the database is created every time but it stops the program so the rest of the code can't be executed.

Comment: And where does it stop at debugging? And why don't you use *plocal*? I mean does this server run somewhere else? You have *localhost* so I need to ask =)

Comment: Yes right now I have localhost but I dont know how it will be later. That error message comes from play framework but I also tried with a simple java app. In that case the message is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.common.listener.OListenerManger.<init>(Z)V

Comment: Well please try *plocal*. I mean uploading a database is fast and easy. And in both cases you need to stop the running database. So there is no real downside. Or do you mean with *plocal* these errors occur?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29417018/4262469) answer solves the problem :)

Comment: @vitorenesduarte Thanks guys. I realized that the problem has nothing to do with my code. (or at least I think that) I tried the same code in a simple Java app and it works wonderful but if I try the same code in a Play Framework project then it doesn't. It stops the app and throws exceptions. No idea why.

Comment: Have your ever met this warning: maj 13, 2015 10:06:36 FM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
VARNING: Requested command 'create vertex type 'User' as subclass of 'V'' must be executed outside active transaction: the transaction will be committed and reopen right after it. To avoid this behavior execute it outside a transaction ?

Comment: Yes @krillov just do it in the following style for the moethods. Here the example for the **createClass** method: *void createClass(final String className) {
  final OrientGraph txGraph = factoryGraph.getTx();
  txGraph.executeOutsideTx(new OCallable<Object, OrientBaseGraph>() {
   public Object call(OrientBaseGraph iArgument) {
    txGraph.createVertexType(className).setClusterSelection("default");
    return null;
   }
  });
 }*

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I was a little bit off from my project for some weeks. I changed my code based on the link you gave me and on what you wrote last time. I made some things differently but it works nice. I'm still using OServerAdmin cause I want a remote DB and I'm using `OSchema schema = graphFactory.getDatabase().getMetadata().getSchema();` instead of using ODatabaseDocumentTx. Your link was really helpful. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you dude =) Better then no answer ;)