# OrientDB: Cannot change the schema while a transaction is active. Schema changes are not transactional

Tags: java, transactions, orientdb

I'm currently evaluating OrientDB with the Java Graph API in embedded mode for usage in future projects. When using the transactional graph implementation in a distributed setup, I'm observing the following issue:

1. After server startup and activation, I obtain a graph instance via OrientGraphFactory::factory.getTx()
2. On the first node, I setup a simple schema as follows:

   ```
   graph.getRawGraph().commit();

   if (graph.getVertexType("Person") == null)
       graph.createVertexType("Person");

   final OrientVertexType vtPerson = graph.getVertexType("Person");
   if (vtPerson.getProperty("firstName") == null)
       vtPerson.createProperty("firstName", OType.STRING);
   if (vtPerson.getProperty("lastName") == null)
       vtPerson.createProperty("lastName", OType.STRING);

   vtPerson.createEdgeProperty(Direction.OUT, "lives");
   vtPerson.createEdgeProperty(Direction.OUT, "history");
   vtPerson.setStrictMode(true);
   ```
3. I shutdown the first node and restart it, then I also launch the second node, after startup I obtain a graph instance as described under (1).
4. On the first node I try to add a vertex:

   ```
   try {
       final OrientVertex person = graph.addVertex("class:Person", "firstName", firstName, "lastName", lastName);
       graph.getRawGraph().commit();
       return person;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       graph.rollback();
   }
   ```

That's when I get an OSchemaException:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Cannot change the schema while a transaction is active. Schema changes are not transactional
DB name="test"
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.saveInternal(OSchemaShared.java:1284)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.releaseSchemaWriteLock(OSchemaShared.java:606)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.releaseSchemaWriteLock(OClassImpl.java:2028)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.releaseSchemaWriteLock(OClassImpl.java:2023)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.setClusterSelectionInternal(OClassImpl.java:2062)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.impl.ODistributedAbstractPlugin.propagateSchemaChanges(ODistributedAbstractPlugin.java:1439)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.impl.ODistributedStorage.checkForCluster(ODistributedStorage.java:1803)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.impl.ODistributedTransactionManager.checkForClusterIds(ODistributedTransactionManager.java:275)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.impl.ODistributedTransactionManager.commit(ODistributedTransactionManager.java:87)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.impl.ODistributedStorage.commit(ODistributedStorage.java:1240)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:569)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:109)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2667)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2637)
```

When using the OrientGraphNoTx implementation instead everything works as expected. However, I'd very much prefer to use the transactional graph, to be able to rollback transactions.

Comment: It's telling you that schema changes aren't transactional. Data changes are.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct - schema changes in Orient are not transactional. You should use a non-transactional operation to create or modify your schema, and a transactional operation to make data changes to the graph.

If you need to perform schema changes as part of your business logic, run them first, and if they fail, fail the data transaction as well. It's important to note that under some conditions, OrientDB will silently commit a transaction in progress if you perform a schema change using a transactional context, so ensure that you **never** do this.

Comment: Where exactly am I performing a schema change, when adding a new Vertex? Also, I already tried to use a non-transactional graph for initially setting up the schema and then use a transactional one to add the vertices. But after adding multiple vertices I get the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

`Where exactly am I performing a schema change, when adding a new Vertex?`

The schema change is done in this `if` block. `createVertexType("Person")` changes the schema.

```
if (graph.getVertexType("Person") == null)
    graph.createVertexType("Person");
```

You're using a transaction when you use call `factory.getTx()` like you mentioned.

```
OrientGraphFactory::factory.getTx()
```

Instead, try

```
graph = new OrientGraphNoTx("your URL");
```

and check here : 
[Create schema for graph database with Java in OrientDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143462/create-schema-for-graph-database-with-java-in-orientdb?rq=1)